# How to include External CSS and JS file in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am Using Laravel 5.0 , the Form and Html Helper are removed from this version , i dont know how to include external css and js files in my header file. Currently i am using this code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!---  css file  --->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you mark the top answer as the answer? As it is valid information and works like you asked.

Answer (score 138):

I think that the right way is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

Here I have a `js` directory in the laravel's `app/public` folder. There I have a `jquery.js` file. The function URL::asset() produces the necessary url for you. Same for the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/somestylesheet.css') }}" />
```

Keep in mind that the old mehods:

```
{{ Form::script() }}
```

and

```
{{ Form::style() }}
```

are deprecated and will not work in Laravel 5!

Comment: Also note that the assets directory in Laravel 5 is not associated with this facade. That confused me for a second, `URL::asset` will literally point to your public folder.

Comment: Yes that's right. You can also use the ```asset()``` helper method. It does the same work.

Comment: Why do you not simply write `src="/js/jquery.js"` and `href="/css/somestylesheet.css"` ?

Comment: I normally use `asset()` and it works. Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: the major difference is, `asset()` works even when you access from sub-directory where as adding `src="/js/jquery.js"` doesn't work as it always expects files at root level and those js files will not be found hence 404s

Answer (score 36):

Try it.

You can just pass the path to the style sheet .

```
{!! HTML::style('css/style.css') !!}
```

You can just pass the path to the javascript.

```
{!! HTML::script('js/script.js') !!}
```

Add the following lines in the require section of  **composer.json** file and run composer update **"illuminate/html": "5.*"**.

Register the service provider in **config/app.php** by adding the following value into the providers array:

`'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'`

Register facades by adding these two lines in the aliases array:

`'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'`

Comment: The HTML and Form Classes are removed from Laravel 5

Comment: I have added the following but this is printing the link on webpage as                                     <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/myapp/public/css/test.css">

Comment: this solved my problem {!! HTML::style('public/css/bootstrap.css') !!}

Comment: Active maintenance on the HTML package has been taken over by the Laravel Collective. http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

Comment: where exactly do we have to write this, {!! HTML::script('js/script.js') !!}, i have js connection problem

Comment: What is exactly the use of those double exclamation mark (!!)?

Answer (score 24):

In laravel 5.1,

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Where assets folder location is inside public folder

Answer (score 17):

i use this way, don't forget to put your css file on public folder.

for example i put my bootstrap css on

```
"root/public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

to access from header:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

hope this help

Answer (score 10):

Place your assets in public directory and use the following

```
URL::to()
```

example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('css/style.css') }}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::to('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

At first, you have to put your `.css` or `.js` files in the `public` folder of your project. You may create subfolders to it and move the files into the subfolder. Then you have to do the followings

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/your_css_file.css')}}">
<script src="{{asset('js/your_js_file.js')}}"></script>
```

In my example, I have created two subfolders called css and js. I put all of the `.css` and `.js` files in corresponding folders and use them where ever I want them. Thank you and hope this helps you.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to include external css and js files as specified in below code but you can choose one of them, i have tested them all, they work the same.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/stylesheet.css') }}" /><!--Recommended-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/somestylesheet.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('css/otherstylesheet.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/anotherstylesheet.css') }}" />
```

Maybe there are more ways to load it.

but keep in mind that if you are loading the css and js from other than a public folder then better to use [`Laravel mix`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix).

Answer (score 6):

```
{{ HTML::style('yourcss.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('yourjs.js') }}
```

Comment: how come? did you try using `URL::asset() or app_path()` ?

Comment: this solved my problem thanks {{ asset('public/css/bootstrap.css') }}

Comment: Instead of `HTML`, it needs to be `Html`.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel 5.5 comes with mix , the replacement for Elixir, the external css(sass) can be extracted to resources/assets/css(sass) and import to app.css(scss) or give the correct path to your node_module folder that contains the library and can be used as

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" >`

The same can be done for Javascript too .

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it only works if you use Mix compiled resources (after generating the versioned file). (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#sass)

Comment: using <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('path/file') }}" > is the new way on 5.5 https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I was able to figure out for the version 5.2. You will first need to create assets folder in your public folder then put css folder and all css files into it then link it like this :

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: My CSS file was not being linked to in my blade view.  The problem was I had put it in /resources/assets/css/ with the blade views, but the solution was I needed to put it in /public/assets/css/

Answer (score 3):

> **CORRECT & SECURED WAY**

---

**If you have a external `.css` or `.js` file to add into your page!**

*My version : Laravel Framework 5.7*

> If you want to add a External `.js` file..

1. Copy your External codes.
2. Run command `npm install` in your terminal.
3. When the above command is executed you can see a folder named `node_modules`.
4. Then go to **resources/js**.
5. Open file `app.js`.
6. Scroll down to the bottom and **paste** your External JS.
7. Finally run command `npm run dev` in your terminal.

your scripts will be updated and its compiled and moved to `public/js/app.js` . by adding a `.js` file in public folder will not effect on your page.

---

> If you want to add a External `.css` file..

1. Copy your External styles.
2. Run command `npm install` in your terminal.
3. When the above command is executed you can see a folder named `node_modules`.
4. Then go to **resources/sass**.
5. Open file `app.scss`.
6. Scroll down to the bottom and **paste** your External Styles.
7. Finally run command `npm run dev` in your terminal.

your scripts will be updated and its compiled and moved to `public/css/app.css` . by adding a `.css` file in public folder will not effect on your page.

- Easiest and the safest way to add your external .css and .js.

Laravel [JavaScript & CSS Scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/frontend)

YouTube [Compiling Assets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSG2YMqJJys)

Answer (score 2):

First you have to install the Illuminate Html helper class:

```
composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"
```

Next you need to open /config/app.php and update as follows:

```
'providers' => [

...

Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [

...

'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class, 
'HTML' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
],
```

To confirm it’s working use the following command:

```
php artisan tinker
> Form::text('foo')
"<input name=\"foo\" type=\"text\">"
```

To include external css in you files, use the following syntax:

```
{!! HTML::style('foo/bar.css') !!}
```

Comment: He said: " Form and Html Helper are removed from this version". He doesn't want to use HTML Helper though..

Comment: This is a way to get that support back in Laravel 5.0 and thus enabling him to use a syntax he is accustomed to, since he specifically states that the support is removed and he don't know of another way to include external files.

Answer (score 1):

I may be late to the party but it's easy to include JS and CSS the Laravel Way by simply using asset() function

e.g.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" />`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I have been making use of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script> 
for javascript and 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/main.css') }}">
for css, this points to the public directory, so you need to keep your css and js files there.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 composer require laravelcollective/html
```

This command will add laracollective/html package in your project,which is very useful in form creating.After that use

```
{!! Html::style('public/css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}

{!! Html::script('public/js/jquery.min.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('public/js/bootstrap.min.js') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

It mostly happens due to laravel webpackmix is not yet executed

composer require laravel/ui
PHP artisan ui vue --auth  //you can use vue boostrap --auth is to add the login paths and

npm install
if it's asking to run "npm fund" then do it
npm run dev

try this once again