# Where to put css file in laravel project

Tags: laravel

I have been searching for an answer to this question with no luck. This is my second day using laravel and I'm trying to create a custom 404 error page. I don't know where/how to include my .css file. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28915577/2215378 worked for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Place your css files inside public folder and use link tag in html document (or 404 template)

Example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('/css/style.css') }}" />
```

Comment: Thank you i am trying that right now. I am so happy for the fast response and so grateful.

Comment: You are welcome. I edited the post, take a look at example

Comment: thank you that worked for me im accepting when i can

Comment: `url()` is NOT the right way to achieve this... instead use `asset()`.

Answer (score 12):

The best way is using blade syntax with the laravel helper for what you need

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">`

this folder `css` or whatever you named it, must be placed inside your public folder.

Comment: I have added `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">` in my `app.blade.css` but i am getting error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: THIS is the right way, not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

1. Search for Public folder in Laravel.
2. Create css folder (that contains stylesheet files of your project), javascript and Images folder (contains images that you will use in your project).

Go to layouts in app.blade.php file update html code using blade syntax:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

and JS:

```
<script src="{{ asset('pickadate/lib/picker.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** put your CSS file in directory [PUBLIC/CSS] 
**2.** in your FileName.blade.php in  file just write :

`<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href={{ asset('css/article.css')}}> </head>`

**Note Again** : Don't Write `asset('public/css/article.css')` this wrong

Answer (score 2):

put it in your public file and the html tags in view then to connect them with the css use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL.asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
```

simply add this your blade.php file