# How to include External CSS and JS file in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am Using Laravel 5.5, the Form and HTML Helper are removed from this version. I don't know how to include external style sheet and JavaScript files in my header file.

Currently I am using this code:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

Comment: You have to write normal `<link>` tag for this. because external css and js will have different path and `{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}` can not be understood by it.

Comment: Your question has answer here, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104583/how-to-include-external-css-and-js-file-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 5):

put your css in public/css and js in public/js and add follow code *.blade.php file

e.g.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.min.css') }}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.min.js') }}"></script>
```