# Laravel page not found

Tags: laravel

When I open the site with the server.php file, my index page is displayed (index.blade.php), and the link on that page to the list page (list.blade.php) opens successfully. I encountered issues with it recognising my javascript files when I access via server.php? However if I open the public folder it puts me at my index page and javascript files are recognised...

When I open the public folder, and I click the list link I get "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {return view('index');});

Route::get('list', 'IngredientsController@display');
```

IngredientsController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Ingredient;

class IngredientsController extends Controller
{
    /* Displays list of ingredients in db */
    public function display()
    {
        $ingredients = Ingredient::all();
        return view('list', compact('ingredients'));
    }

}
```

ingredient.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ingredient extends Model
{

}
```

link on index page to list page: `<a href="{{ url('list') }}">List url</a>`

htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your code above isn't really relevant to your question.

Comment: You shouldn't be going to `domain.com/public/somethingelse` it should just be `domain.com/somethingelse` check your .htaccess file.

Comment: not sure why code was not relevant sorry. i think because i have no clue how to address this i provided you what i did know. and i am on uni server. it goes something like domain.com/me/project/projectdirectory and here i see all files in directory. it doesnt just open up the index.

Comment: have you enabled mod_rewrite

Comment: i added the htaccess file but ill admit im not all that knowledgable on this so i will look into that now. thanks.

Comment: From what i can tell my htaccess file is OK. Also the public route is normal in laravel and for my current purposes fine. If I change it to domain.com it is still looking for the public folder in order to work. See [https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/structure#the-public-directory].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above `RewriteEngine On` I put `Options +FollowSymLinks` and above `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` I added `RewriteBase /nameoflaravelproject/public/`

I added these two lines of code and it works. Sorry I dont really understand this so if someone can explain to provide a better resource for other users then thats great.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn’t use the root for including the files. So yes your IDEA see your files includes correctly but laravel it doesn’t.

See this post answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28915577/5334073

Laravel uses the public folder as the ‘root’ folder. That’s just how Laravel works. To call that root you should use the URL::assets function as explain the the answer from the post I gave you.

Comment: I already do this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>`.