# Laravel-5.2 Css and js not working without asset

Tags: jquery, html, css, laravel-5

My CSS and JS file in public folder on localhost, but Its not working. I use laravel 5.2. I tried a lot of ways but still failed.

I don't want to use ,
`<link href="{{asset('/css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

I used :

`<link href="public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">`

But It's not working.
 Please, give me solution. What do I do about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to create **assets** folder in your **public** folder then put **css** folder and all css files into it then link it like this :

```
<link href="assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope that helps you!

For more [view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104583/how-to-include-external-css-and-js-file-in-laravel-5) this

**Update** as per comment

check your .htaccess file use this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Hope this work

Comment: But, This project create our previous developer. this project already created and run successfully.
I have set in local. He used ,e.g., `<script src="/public/assets/frontends/script/jquery.mixitup.js"></script>` But It's not working without changes.
It's possible.
Please say to me, What I do?

Comment: You mean the project work in live properly but locally linking not working?

Comment: Yes, the previous developer used it and live in run, but not working in my option.
Can other setting, that i forgate.

Comment: check the update ans hope it will help you maybe you forget to update your .htaccess settings.

Comment: Sorry,.htaccess settings not work.
I writed :
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>`

Response :

`**Not Found
The requested URL /public/help was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/7.2.4 Server at localhost Port 80**`

Comment: Sorry Don't get this problem but pretty sure that it's a htaccess problem.