# How can i connect downloaded js library(leaflet.js) on pages in my laravel project?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, leaflet, node-modules

My problem is what i don't know how to connect js library leaflet.js( it downloaded and located in node_modules) on page with map in my laravel project. [leaflet's site](https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/download.html) says that i should add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/leaflet.css" />
<script src="/path/to/leaflet.js"></script>
```

and write path to library in these src's, but i don't know how to get it, i've tryed to do some operations with laravel mix but it didn't helped me(or i did something wrong, idk)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include External CSS and JS file in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104583/how-to-include-external-css-and-js-file-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to add the CSS and js file. In you downloaded a full zipped folder then out it to public folder with the name `leaflet`.Then Add the following code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('leaflet/to/leaflet.css')}} " />
<script src="{{ asset('leaflet/to/leaflet.js') }} "></script>
```

Next, if you can be downloading through the following command:

```
npm install leaflet
```

Then add required within your `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file.

```
require("leaflet");
```